# What exactly is AC Amperes

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current

In the case of AC, electrons don't go anywhere. So what exactly are amperes in the case of AC current? It is supposed to be the measure of AC current, But obviously, I would argue that since electrons don't really go anywhere in an AC circuit, current as such cannot be measured.

So how do instruments measure amperes in an AC current? I understand that we could measure AC power within a circuit as the force with which the electrons vibrate within a circuit. So, lower the vibration, lower the wattage. All good. It appears that the amperes within an ac circuit are measured simply on the firm belief that voltage input is fixed - which is 110 V or whatever it is expected to be in that region.

So, let's say that I produce an AC current by pedaling a turbine with my legs. Then, how exactly do we measure AC voltage and current? According to me AC power could be measured, but not AC voltage or current. They would simply cancel out, or no?

Comment: I have submitted an edit to this question for approval. Kindly refrain from using ... (ellipsis) in place of regular punctuation (comma, full stop) in your question.

Comment: The current is the same as in DC, charge flowing per unit of time, it just turns out that the current goes back and forth, it has a time dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to measure the intensity and direction of a continuous current by the deflection of a magnet needle like the Oersted experiment.

In the case of AC, we know that something similar is happening in the wire, because of the joule effect and other energy productions. But if we place a compass nearby, the needle doesn't move.

But if we make a coil of wire over a iron core, it works as an electromagnet, that attracts iron with a magnitude that depends on the current. And the attraction is not affected by the change of polarity because what is being attracted is not a permanent magnet, but just an iron object.

That device can be placed inside a clamp meter, where the magnetic field of the wire being measured induces an emf (and a current) on this electromagnet. An iron needle is deflected proportional to induced current, that is proportional to the magnetic field, that is proportional to the wire AC current.

Comment: Loved this answer... Still.. is that how - say for example - a real device like the ammeter measure AC current?

Comment: So then basically what you are also saying is that irrespective of the direction of the charge, the charge is moving in some direction at any given moment as if in a circle. And the attraction of the iron piece is proportional to that movement... And as a corollary, the voltage is similar to the measure of the distance which the charge travels and the amplitude of the sine wave... and will also be related to frequency... I think I get it now.

Comment: I'll take this as an answer... Would love to also know how voltage would be measured if you can explain

Answer (score 0):

No, it's still very straightforward to measure current. Current is the amount of charge flowing through a point at any instant, which is well defined as $I(t) = I_o \cos(\omega t)$ for AC. Conventionally, when we give current we take the RMS current for AC (i.e. $I_{RMS} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0 |I(t)|^2dt}$ ).

As an analogy, imagine a bunch of cars going forward and backward on a road. Count the number of tires that cross a line on the road per minute. That's the current.

Comment: The RMS current you defined is identically zero. $I(t)$ should be $I^{2}(t)$ for the expression to have correct dimensions.

Comment: @Newbie thanks, did that in my head but not on paper

Answer (score 0):

> In the case of AC, electrons don't go anywhere.

Although the average value of sinusoidal AC current is zero (since the average value of a sinusoidal waveform is zero), that doesn't mean there is no motion of the electrons, that the electrons don't undergo collisions due to that motion, and that energy in the form of heat is not dissipated in the conductors carrying the electrons.

Consider a mechanical analogy involving friction. Consider first an analogy with DC current.

I push a box along the floor at constant velocity a distance $d$ between two points on the floor. (1) I am the mechanical analog of the force applied by the DC electric field (2) the box is analogous to a coulomb of electrons, (3) the movement of the electrons at constant velocity is analogous to dc current and (4) the floor is analogous to a resistor. I do work positive work on the box and friction does an equal amount of negative work taking the energy I give the box and dissipating it as heat, analogous to heat given off by a resistor.

Now, consider the analogy for AC current.

Instead of pushing the box at constant velocity in one direction a distance $d$, I push it forwards and pull it backwards a number of times so that the total back and forth distance equals $d$, though the box has not gone anywhere. Nevertheless, the same amount of heat due to friction will be generated as in the case of pushing the box in one direction a distance $d$.  So although the average "current" is zero, the heating effect is not. For that reason, we normally refer to the RMS value of the ac current since it provides the equivalent heating effect of DC current.

> So how do instruments measure amperes in an AC current?

There are a many different types of AC ammeters. I'm not an expert on meters, but one of the analog types involves the D'Arsonval meter design. Essentially, the current is passed through a wire coil located between the poles of a permanent magnet. The interaction between the magnetic field generated by the current in the coil with the field of the permanent magnet causes the needle to deflect.

However, since alternating current would result in useless flutter of the needle, the instrument uses a rectifier to convert AC to DC current. The meter scale usually displays the RMS value of the AC current.

> Then, how exactly do we measure AC voltage...?

An analog D'Arnsonval AC volt meter involves essentially the same meter movement and rectifier as the ammeter, except instead of the low input impedance of the ammeter, a properly selected meter will have a high input impedance relative to the impedance of the circuit so as to have minimal effect on the voltage being measured.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That amounts to only a measure of power or wattage or heat as you mentioned. It has no relation to a measure of current or voltage. What I'm asking is the basis of a measure of current or voltage. If it is defined as the amount of charge crossing a particular point, there is a very minimal amount of charge passing a particular charge in case of AC current

Comment: @Nagendra I don't understand what you mean by "there is a very minimal amount of charge passing a particular charge". What do you mean by a charge passing a charge?

Comment: @Nagendra Do you or do you not agree that the power dissipated in a resistor for ac current is $$P=I^2R$$ where $I$ is the RMS value of the current?

Comment: @Nagendra Waiting for your answer.

Comment: @NagendraI don’t know why you haven’t answered, but of course the equation is correct. And since it is, then obviously your statement "That amounts to only a measure of power or wattage or heat as you mentioned. It has no relation to a measure of current or voltage." is incorrect. The drift velocity of the charge is very small regardless of whether the current is dc or ac.

Comment: The only difference is the drift velocity in the case of ac constantly changes direction while for dc it does not. So that is irrelevant. What's more, your statement in your original question "It appears that the amperes within an ac circuit are measured simply on the firm belief that voltage input is fixed” is also incorrect. The voltage, like the current, varies sinusoidally and is not fixed.

Comment: Bottom line, I’m afraid I can’t help you since it is unclear what your issue with ac current is. Hope you find the answer you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I disagree. Im not asking for formulas which has no meaning when the basis of the formula is not clear. Lets say there are 10 ppl standing in a line and move a bucket of water by one step and then move back one step, they have done some work (watts or in your example heat/friction), But the current (amperes) is defined as the amount of charge which moves across a given line. In which case it is always 1.. or in case of electricity the number of electrons in a given cross section of the conductor. There is a very minimal amount of charge passing a particular 'point'/cross section

Comment: @Nagendra I think I now understand what you don't understand. The charge is not just moving back and forth at one point. It is moving back and forth everywhere in the circuit. As soon as an electric field is applied, it exerts a force at almost the speed of light everywhere in the circuit so that the electrons at every point in the circuit are moving back and forth.

Comment: ok... so how is that value measured practically? How does a measuring device calculate or sense / identify that amount of charge which move? The longer the wire the charge will be higher?n Coz a longer wire will obviously have more moving charge

Comment: @Nagendra I told you in my answer with the example of the D'Arsonval  meter. It appears I can't get through to you. So I am finished with this discussion as it appears to be a waste of my time.

Comment: I sure appreciate the attempt to answer though.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for being irritable